# Keras custom metrics with more than two inputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a VAE model that I've broken down into the encoder and decoder parts, and implemented a custom loss.  A simplified example is as below

```
input = Input(shape=(self.image_height, self.image_width, self.image_channel))
encoded = build_encoder(input)
decoded = build_decoder(encoded)
model = Model(input, decoded)
```

The loss (simplified) is

```
loss = K.mean(decoded[0] + decoded[1] + encoded[0]**2)
model.add_loss(loss)
model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer)
```

My main problem is that I want to use Keras' modelcheckpoint function, which would then require me to set custom metrics.  However, everything I have seen online is similar to https://keras.io/metrics/#custom_metrics.  This only takes in y_true and y_pred, and modify the validation loss from there.  How would I implement it in my example model, where the loss is calculated from multiple inputs, not only the final output of "decoded"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add\_loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063613/add-loss-function-in-keras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently you can still use the variables (keras layers) without passing those into the custom loss function.

So for my example, the loss can be calculated as

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(decoded[0] + decoded[1] + encoded[0]**2)

model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=custom_loss)
```

y_true and y_pred is never used, but the actual required inputs can still be called (as long as they are in the same scope as the custom loss function of course).