# Train with target data generated within the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

How can I get the loss function used by `tf.keras.Model.fit(x, y)` to compare two outputs within the graph instead of one output with externally supplied target data, `y`?

[image: Graph showing desired input to loss function]

The manual says you can use tensors for target value which sounds like what I want but that you then also need the inputs to be tensors. But my inputs are numpy arrays and I don't think I should have to change that.

Comment: You could create another layer comparing the two tensors within the graph and then propagate the result (distance metric) to the output to be, e.g., minimised (target y = 0).

Comment: But that output would then go through the "real" loss function, no? Seems possible but with a redundant loss calculation. It would be great if Model.fit() could just minimize the output instead of needing a loss function.

Comment: Exactly, solution 2 by Daniel Möller is what I meant.

Comment: Just found out about option 3, take a look. It sounds pretty clean and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 - Easy, best - maybe not good for memory

Why not just get the expected items for the loss already?

```
new_y_train = non_trainable_ops_model.predict(original_y_train)   
nn_model.fit(x_train, new_y_train)
```

This sounds definitely the best way if your memory can handle this. Simpler model, faster training.

You can even save/load the new data:

```
np.save(name, new_y_train)   
new_y_train = np.load(name)
```

### 2 - Make the model output the loss and use a dummy loss for compiling

Losses:

```
def dummy_loss(true, pred):
    return pred

def true_loss(x):
    true, pred = x

    return loss_function(true, pred) #you can probably from keras.losses import loss_function
```

Model:

```
#given
nn_model = create_nn_model()
non_trainable_ops_model = create_nto_model()

nn_input = Input(nn_input_shape)
nto_input = Input(nto_input_shape)

nn_outputs = nn_model(nn_input)
nto_outputs = non_trainable_ops_model(nto_input)

loss = Lambda(true_loss)([nto_outputs, nn_outputs])

training_model = Model([nn_input, nto_input], loss)
training_model.compile(loss = dummy_loss, ...)

training_model.fit([nn_x_train, nto_x_train], np.zeros((len(nn_x_train),)))
```

### 3 - Use `model.add_loss` instead of compiling a loss

Following the same as the previous answer, you can:

```
training_model = Model([nn_input, nto_input], nn_outputs)

loss = true_loss([nto_outputs, nn_outputs])
training_model.add_loss(loss)

training_model.compile(loss=None, ...)
training_model.fit([nn_x_train, nto_x_train], None)
```

### 4 - Enable eager execution and make custom training loops

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Comment: I'm using option 3. It seems like a 5th way is to make a custom loss function wrapper to pass to Model.compile() according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56514531/1318499 .