# What is the functionality of add_loss() in defining new keras layers?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I am referring to this Variational Autoencoder code [in github](https://github.com/bojone/vae/blob/master/vae_keras_celeba.py) for CelebA dataset. There is an encoder and decoder as usual. The encoder outputs x which is used to get the *log variance* and mean of the posterior distribution. Now the reparameterization trick gives us the encoded

```
z = sigma * u + mean
```

where u comes from normal distribution with mean = 0 and variance = 1. I can figure all of this in the code. However in the 'ScaleShift' class, which is a new keras layer, I don't understand why we are using **add_loss(lodget)**. I checked the [Keras documentation for writing your own layers](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and there doesn't seem to be a requirement for defining loss for a layer. I am confused by what this line's functionality is.

```
#new keras layer
class ScaleShift(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScaleShift, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, inputs):
        z, shift, log_scale = inputs
        #reparameterization trick
        z = K.exp(log_scale) * z + shift
        #what are the next two lines doing?
        logdet = -K.sum(K.mean(log_scale, 0))
        self.add_loss(logdet)
        return z

#gets the mean parameter(z_shift) from x, and similarly the log variance parameter(z_log_scale)
z_shift = Dense(z_dim)(x)
z_log_scale = Dense(z_dim)(x)
#keras lambda layer, spits out random normal variable u of same dimension as z_shift
u = Lambda(lambda z: K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(z)))(z_shift)
z = ScaleShift()([u, z_shift, z_log_scale])

x_recon = decoder(z)
x_out = Subtract()([x_in, x_recon])

recon_loss = 0.5 * K.sum(K.mean(x_out**2, 0)) + 0.5 * np.log(2*np.pi) * np.prod(K.int_shape(x_out)[1:])
#KL divergence loss
z_loss = 0.5 * K.sum(K.mean(z**2, 0)) - 0.5 * K.sum(K.mean(u**2, 0))
vae_loss = recon_loss + z_loss

vae = Model(x_in, x_out)
#VAE loss to be optimised 
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-4))
```

Comment: Your question has been answered in this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063613/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-add-loss-function-in-keras

Comment: @BrentRohner Thanks but I have referred to that post many times. That helped me understand why it is used in `vae.add_loss(vae_loss)` but not in layer definition.