# KL loss function throws type error in keras tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss

I used some tutorials of vae to launch my code. The only problem I couldn't cope with loss function. If I simply use only KL div loss ( just got one by one from tutorial) :

```
z_mean = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_mean')(encoded)
z_log_var = Dense(self.latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(encoded)

def vae_loss(x, decoded):
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
  return kl_loss
```

Then I got error under training

> TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.

The error is not happen when I use another loss for example:

```
def vae_loss(x, decoded):
  mse_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(x, decoded)
  return mse_loss
```

Architecture of vae is following:

[image: net arch]

So how to fix this error and what's the reason?

**Edit**

I found that problem is that there is KerasTensor in loss function. To fix this problem we need to use trick with 'add_loss' function to give mu and sigma params to loss function. You could look at [What is the purpose of the add_loss function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063613/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-add-loss-function-in-keras) for similar problem

Comment: I think there is a problem with the returned variable. Try to convert it to a numpy array before returning. Additionally you could check what is returned by the mean_squared_error function.

Comment: mse_loss return tensor, while kl_loss - keras tensor

Comment: Where does the error occurs exactly?

Comment: somewhere inside tensorflow execution. keras_tensor.py:273 to be certain

Comment: I think the problem is due to the eager execution. If you use a custom loss function you may need to turn off eager execution with :
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

Comment: Second idea: if you're importing keras explicitly, then try changing it to import through tensorflow (import tensorflow.keras instead of import keras)

Comment: 2nd idea has no effect at all. after 1st idea error has been changed on "ValueError("Variable {} has `None` for gradient. ") "