# keras VAE custom training step ValueError: No loss to optimize

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to create a VAE for tabular data - I am using the general structure provided in the keras documentation: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/

I have two networks the `encoder` and `decoder` which are passed to the main class below:

```
# Class for the VAE
class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
    """VAE """
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        
        """Custom training for our custom loss function"""
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data) # Retrieve latents
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z) # Reconstrut the latents
            # Calculate the loss
            reconstruction_loss = tf.keras.losses.mse(data, reconstruction)
            kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss
        
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights) # Gradients of total loss recorded wrt weights via backprop
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights)) # SGD optimized 
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }
```

Running the following code should work:

```
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(data, epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```

But I get `ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.` So I thought to add the loss function to the compiler, but that again did not work since I need to pass `z_log_var, z_mean` into the loss function as well as the true and predicted data which is 4 arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: This thread was particularly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063613/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-add-loss-function-in-keras