# how to build custom loss function with Keras

Tags: keras

I have loss function which implemented for siamese network. In Keras if you have to build your own loss function, it should only take input arguments as (y_true, y_pred). 
But in my case I have y_pred1, y_pred1, y_true1(class_label), y_true2(class_label), y_true3(similarity label)

So my solution is to concatenate what I have like:

```
def my loss ( y_true, y_pred):
    y_true1 = y_true[:, 0]
    y_true2 = y_true[:, 1]
    label = y_true[:, 2]

    y_pred1 = y_pred[:, 0]
    y_pred2 = y_pred[:, 1]
```

The second problem is,  I have one parameter (alpha) which is a function of current epoch number that I should pass it to the loss function also.

In general , if you have to pass some another argument you can use the wrapper function as the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras).

But it will not help me in my case , because my alpha should be change depending on the current number of epoch. It is basically the Sigmoied function of the current epoch.

The only way that I can track the epoch number is inside my own generator, because I have dataset built in tfrecords. So I am using my own generator to feed the data to model.

So any one have any idea what should I do? How I can track the current epoch number and use it.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important! Which of these is your case?

- Case 1: A model with 3 outputs
- Case 2: A model with one output that is a concatenation of three outputs?

## Examples Without alpha

### Case 1

You need three independent loss functions, each function will see only its own `y_true` and `y_pred`.

```py
def loss1(yTrue,yPred):
    ...
def loss2(yTrue,yPred):
    ...
def loss3(yTrue,yPred):
    ...

model.compile(loss=[loss1,loss2,loss3],...)
```

### Case 2

In this case, you will be able to do it the way you proposed.

```py
def my loss ( y_true, y_pred):
    y_true1 = y_true[:, 0]
    y_true2 = y_true[:, 1]

    y_pred1 = y_pred[:, 0]
    y_pred2 = y_pred[:, 1]
```

## Using alpha

Alpha must be a "tensor", not an ordinary var:

```py
alpha = K.variable(someInitialNpArray, dtype=...)
```

The value of alpha must be "changed", not reassigned:

```py
K.set_value(alpha, newValues)
```

Now, create a `LambdaCallback` for `on_epoch_end` in order to change the value of alpha:

```py
def changeAlpha(epoch,logs):
    #maybe use epoch+1, because it starts with 0
    K.set_value(alpha, valuesBasedOn(epoch))

alphaChanger = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=changeAlpha) #or on_epoch_begin (or start?)
```

Loss:

```py
def loss(true,pred):
    #blablabla

    #you can use alpha here
```

Training:

```py
model.fit(..... callbacks = [alphaChanger])
model.fit_generator(......, callbacks = [alphaChanger])
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. My model is with two separate output, but the loss function depend on the two output, so I don't want to use two losses, I will stack the two output along dimension 0 then I will use one loss function and the solution of the second case you mentioned it. And many thanks to you for your suggestion related the alpha parameter. I was so confused since I am new to Keras and I was to return back to pure tensor flow code because of this problem. I will try to implement it.

Comment: @Ddaniel Mooller . Another related question if you may.  If I want to get the values of features after each epoch in order to use it in the ( t-sne) for visualization, Do I need to create LambdaCallback for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know that the t-sne is, but probably yes. You must "model.predict" in order to get the results.

Comment: You seemed too qualified for custom loss function, can you look at my  question here, it is kind of similar issue with some additional complication. I will appreciate if you can look at it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269603/multiple-losses-for-imbalanced-dataset-with-keras