# Multiple losses for imbalanced dataset with Keras

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

**My Model**:

I built a siamese network that take two input and has three outputs. So My loss functions is :

```
total loss = alpha( loss1) + alpah( loss2) + (1_alpah) ( loss3)
```

`loss1` and `loss2` is `categorical cross entropy` loss function, to classify the class identity from total of 8 classes. 
`loss3` is `similarity loss` function ( euclidean distance loss), to verify if the both input from same class or different classes.

**My questions are as follow:**

1. If I have different losses, and I want to weight them by using the variable `alpha` which its value depend on the epoch number. So I have to set the value pf  `alpha` through callback. My question is it possible to pass this alpha variable that its value changed with epoch number (i.e not scalar) through the `loss_weights` in `model.complie`. The documentation said:

> loss_weights: Optional list or dictionary specifying scalar
>   coefficients (Python floats) to weight the loss contributions of
>   different model outputs. The loss value that will be minimized by the
>   model will then be the weighted sum of all individual losses, weighted
>   by the loss_weights coefficients. If a list, it is expected to have a
>   1:1 mapping to the model's outputs. If a tensor, it is expected to map
>   output names (strings) to scalar coefficients.

**Example**

```
alpha = K.variable(0., dtype=tf.float32)

def changeAlpha(epoch,logs):
    new_alpha = some_function(epoch)
    K.set_value(alpha, new_alpha)
    return

alphaChanger = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=changeAlpha) 

model.compile(loss= [loss1, loss2, loss3], loss_weights = [alpha, alpha, (1-alpha)])
```

2. My dataset is imbalanced, so I want to use `class_wights` in `model.fit()`. So for the same model of three losses, I want to apply the `class weights` only for categorical cross entropy losses ( loss 1 and loss2) , So will it work on both losses and except the third loss if I pass it to `model.fit`? Knowing that the third loss is **custom** loss function.
3. If I want to classify the classes for siamese network, would my  metric be `model.compile(metrics= ['out1':'accuracy', 'out2':accuracy']])`? But the final accuracy need to be the average of both,I can solve it by building my own custom metric. But is there anyway to weighted summing of both metrics.