# Keras custom loss, having error in batch size in y_true and y_pred

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I want to create a custom loss function, where I want to use my pre calculated y_true, but unfortunately, when I use that I am having error with the batch size not matching with y_pred. I am interested to know the work around. Here is the example code of my custom loss.

```
  def avg_vect_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    #y_true need not to be used, instead pos_avg_vects and neg_avg_vects are considered as my pre calculated y_trues
     pos_avg_vects, neg_avg_vects = pos_neg_avg_vects()
     l2_dist_to_pos_avg = l2_distance_loss(y_pred, pos_avg_vects)
     l2_dist_to_neg_avg = l2_distance_loss(y_pred, neg_avg_vects)
     return l2_dist_to_pos_avg/l2_dist_to_neg_avg
```

Code is commented. My loss function is trying to maximize l2 distance between y_pred to neg_avg_vec and minimize l2_distance between y_pred and pos_avg_vec. I am having error because of batch size mismatch between my y_pred and pos_avg_vects, neg_avg_vects.

pos_avg_vector and neg_avg_vector are the average vectors of the nearest and farthest neighbours of y_true.

Please note, y_true, y_pred are the word vectors. My training set and test set consists of word vectors of corresponding words.

Comment: And what is the definition of `pos_neg_avg_vects()` function?

Comment: pos_avg_vector and neg_avg_vector are the average vectors of the nearest and farthest 4 neighbours of y_true. I edited my post accordingly

Comment: Please share the code of `pos_neg_avg_vects` and `l2_distance_loss`. otherwise it's impossible to help you. Also, please provide more detailed information about the error. In which line is it happening? What exactly does it say regarding the shapes that do not match?