# Need custom loss function that uses if statement

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to train DNN that outputs 3 values `(x,y,z)` where `x` and `y` are coordinates of the object I'm looking for and `z` is the probability that object is present

I need custom loss function:

If `z_true<0.5` I don't care of `x` and `y` values, so error should be equal to `(0, 0, sqr(z_true - z_pred))`

otherwise error should be like `(sqr(x_true - x_pred), sqr(y_true - y_pred), sqr(z_true - z_pred))`

I'm in a struggle with mixing tensors and if statements together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `switch` from Keras backend: https://keras.io/backend/#switch
It is similar to `tf.cond` 
How to create a custom loss in Keras described here: [Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example of a custom loss function will get you up and running. It shows how you can mix tensors with if statements.

```
 def conditional_loss_function(l):
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            if l == 0: 
                return loss_funtion1(y_true, y_pred)
            else: 
                return loss_funtion2(y_true, y_pred)
        return loss

 model.compile(loss=conditional_loss_function(l), optimizer=...)
```

Comment: in this way, I have to know `l` before compiling model and if I will generate new samples for every epoch, I won't be able to change `l` anymore?

Comment: I assume you could write a custom generator that calculates „l“ depending on the current batch you are processing. Then you could call that function to update the value of „l“ in the lossfunction.