# Custom loss function not differentiable with threshold

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am hoping to build a model with custom loss function and came across this post [Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras)

```
            def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth,thresh):
                y_pred = y_pred>thresh #line with question
                y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
                y_pred_f = K.flatten(tf.cast(y_pred,tf.float32))
                intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
                return (2. * intersection +smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
            def dice_loss(smooth,thresh):
              def dice(y_true, y_pred):
                return dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth,thresh)
              return dice

            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=X_train_vectorized.shape[1]))
            model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=dice_loss(smooth=1e-5,thresh=0.5),
                            metrics=[metrics.mae, metrics.categorical_accuracy])
            model.fit(X_train_vectorized, y_train, nb_epoch=5, validation_data=(X_test_vectorized, y_test))
```

When I run above lines, `y_pred = y_pred>thresh` would throw an error as a gradient is not defined. I do not have enough reputation to comment on the origin post.

How should I convert the predicted probabilities to binary outputs? Thanks.

Comment: `tf.clip_by_value` might even work.

Comment: Wondering if you were able to solve this and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can just gather the predictions that satisfies your condition:

```
y_pred = tf.gather(y_pred, tf.where(y_pred>thresh))
```

Since tf.gather is a differentiable operation (it behaves like a multiplication with a sparse matrix) you should be able to compute your loss and affecting only the value that satisfied the condition when backpropagating the error.

Comment: I followed your answer here and am getting `ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[662885,4,144,144,1]`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: The input tensor is too huge. Split it and loop through the splits. Btw it's better to ask a new question