# Regarding custom loss in keras , hyperas

Tags: keras

How can I define custom loss functions in Hyperas?

I am running a 4 dense layers architecture with 3 outputs. For the loss, i would like to define it as:

```
Loss

( (Output1 Error) / max[Output1_pred, Output1_true] ) +
( (Output2 Error) / max[Output2_pred, Output2_true] ) +
( (Output3 Error) / max[Output3_pred, Output3_true] )
```

Is this trivial to accomplish? How can I index y_pred and y_true in such a case?

Comment: for the vectorized form, what does axis = 1 do?

Comment: so basically the `np.hstack()` will combine both Output_pred and Output_true in a single array, with `np.max` picking out the largest value. so the loss will be just a single scaler using the `np.sum()` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187541/discussion-between-anand-v-singh-and-corse).

Comment: minor correction `np.amax()` not `np.max()`

Answer (score 0):

To make a custom loss function in keras follow this [Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras)

Now to vectorize your loss function, so that you don't have extremely slow speed, use vectorization, to do that you can write your loss function as :

`loss = np.sum(np.divide(Output_Error,np.amax(np.hstack((Output_pred,Output_true)),axis=1)))`

Now let's break this down

`np.hstack((M1,M2))` stacks the matrices as [M1|M2] which are both vectors in your case.

`np.amax(M,axis = 1)` creates a vector of maximum values along x axis i.e. for each row.

`np.divide(M1,M2)` Performs element wise division across matrices so you will still get a vector.

`np.sum(M)` provides scalar sum of the matrix M.

To learn more about any of these functions, visit https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/

If you have any queries comment down below.

Comment: so i did this and it said: hstack() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Edited accordingly and more information available in chat @Corse