# am trying to implement my own custom loss function in Keras, But it not work

Tags: loss-function

The losses have remained the same and have not fallen as expected. Here is my Code to test if the loss function work well：

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.sigmoid(-200 * (y_pred - 1.05)))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss=ml.my_loss,
              metrics=['mae', ml.my_metrics])
```

and here is the output:

5000/28976 [====>.........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0000 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0406 - my_metrics: 0.0000e+00
10000/28976 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0000 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0412 - my_metrics: 0.0000e+00
15000/28976 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0000 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0412 - my_metrics: 0.0000e+00
20000/28976 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0000 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0411 - my_metrics: 0.0000e+00
28976/28976 [==============================] - 0s 10us/step - loss: 1.0000 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0407 - my_metrics: 0.0000e+00

Comment: it keeps 1 in all training time.

Comment: what's my_ls?, i don't think `tf.reduce_mean` has that parameter, read this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean

Comment: i think it should be `tf.reduce_mean(tf.sigmoid(-200 * (y_pred -1.05)))`, try that and let me know if it's still a problem?

Comment: yes u r right. ti's still a problem.
    def  my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.sigmoid(-200 * (y_pred - 1.05)))

Comment: so did it work? @zzm

Comment: no, it keep at 1.0000.

Comment: okay, so your model.compile has an argument, loss=ml.my_loss? why don't you use my_loss instead?

Comment: because the function defined in the other file, I have import it as ml

Comment: in my opinion, it will be get zero, because the model can change the y_pred to a large number to get a min loss.

Comment: check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras

Comment: Thanks, it not the same reason, that question's problem is to rename loss funcion's parameter's name. but in my code, it is ‘y_true, y_pred’, it not need a wrapper.

Comment: it works when i change the function to : tf.reduce_mean(tf.sigmoid(-(y_pred - 1.05))), remove coefficient（200） Thanks.

Comment: glad to know it worked out!