# Keras custom loss function yields weird result

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to write a custom loss function of weighted binary cross-entropy in Keras. However, when I compiled my model with the custom loss function, both of the loss and the accuracy went down. Normally the accuracy is around 90% when I train the model with plain BCE, but it came down to 3-10% when I used my custom loss function. Here is my custom loss function:

```
def weighted_crossentropy_core(y_true, y_pred, pos_weight, neg_weight):

    wcel = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    weight = y_true * pos_weight + (1.0 - y_true) * neg_weight
    wcel = K.mean(weight * cel)

    return wcel

def weighted_crossentropy_wrapper(pos_weight=1, neg_weight=1):
    def weighted_crossentropy_return(y_true, y_pred):
        return weighted_crossentropy_core(y_true, y_pred, pos_weight, neg_weight)
    return weighted_crossentropy_return

wcel = weighted_crossentropy_wrapper()
model.compile(Adam(init_lr), loss=wcel, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The most weird thing is that when I wrapped the tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy loss function and then sent the wrapper in (which is essentially the same as keras' bce loss), the resulting losses were totally different from those I got when passing keras bce without the wrapper! Here is how I wrap the bce:

```
def wrapped_bce(y_true, y_pred):

    bce = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

    return bce

wcel = wrapped_bce()
model.compile(Adam(init_lr), loss=wcel, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I wrap my loss function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To wrap your loss in the second example, you should use `wcel = wrapped_bce` (without parenthesis).

Same thing in the first example, but your function `weighted_crossentropy_wrapper` is a wrapper around another wrapper and omits `y_true` and `y_pred`, this looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: Sorry for the error here. I just ran:
```
model.compile(Adam(init_lr), loss=wrapped_bce, metrics=["accuracy"])
```
And it still gave me weird loss and accuracy different from that of keras bce.

Comment: For the first example I followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras

Comment: OK, I understand what you did in the first example. About your differing results with and without wrapper, this is strange. The wrapper shouldn't have any influence on the results. Do you retrain your model before comparing the results (in which case you will have a discrepancy) or just recompile it?

Comment: I recompile the model.