# Accuracy metric fails with trivial custom Keras loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am playing around with custom loss functions on Keras models. My "custom" loss seems to fail (in terms of accuracy score), even though I am only using a wrapper that returns an original keras loss.

As a toy example, I am using the ["Basic classification"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) Tensorflow/Keras tutorial that uses a simple NN on the fashion-MNIST data set and I am following the related Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/losses/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras) SO post.

---

This is the model:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Now, if I leave the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as a string argument in `compile()` function, the training results to a ~ 87% accuracy which is fine:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

But when I just create a trivial wrapper function to call keras' cross-entropy I get a ~ 10% accuracy both on training and test sets:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import losses

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=my_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

> Epoch 1/10 60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 51us/sample - loss: 0.5030 - accuracy: 0.1032
>   Epoch 2/10 60000/60000 [==============================] - 3s 45us/sample - loss: 0.3766 - accuracy: 0.1035
>
> ...
>
> Test accuracy: 0.1013

---

By plotting a few images and checking their classified labels, it doesn't look like the results differ in each case, but accuracies printed are very different. So, is it the case that the default metrics do not play nicely with custom losses? Can it be the case that what I see is the error rather than the accuracy? Am I missing something from the documentation?

**Edit:** The values of the loss functions in both cases end up roughly the same, so training indeed takes place. The accuracy is the point of failure.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about how the example from Keras uses `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for a `(n, 10)` target array. Usually, 'sparse' means it expects a `(n, 1)` array. Have you tried `losses.categorical_crossentropy`?

Comment: You should use `sparse_categorical_accuracy` as your metrics instead of `accuracy`.

Comment: @NicolasGervais But the target array is indeed a `(n, 1)` array. (The error message also says it so if you pass the `categorical_crossentropy` loss)

Comment: @bit01 You are right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the reason:
When you use inbuilt loss and use `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` at that time accuracy metric used is `sparse_categorical_accuracy` But when you use custom loss function at that time accuracy metric used is `categorical_accuracy`.

Example:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 'sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)
'''
Train on 60000 samples
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 86us/sample - loss: 0.4955 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1045 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8255
'''


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=my_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy', 'sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)

'''
Train on 60000 samples
60000/60000 [==============================] - 5s 87us/sample - loss: 0.4956 - acc: 0.1043 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8256
'''
```

Comment: Clear enough. Thank you.