# Custom loss and accuracy in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I want to extend the output of the network to two outputs in this code

```
# Model architecture
  input = Input(shape = (max_len,))
  model = Embedding(input_dim = len(words) + 2, output_dim = embedding, input_length = max_len, mask_zero = True)(input)
  model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)
  model = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="relu"))(model)
  crf = CRF(num_tags+1)  # CRF layer
  out = crf(model)  # output

  model = Model(input, out)
  model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])
```

(The original code is at https://github.com/Akshayc1/named-entity-recognition.git). I want the loss function to be the summation of losses for these two outputs, and accuracy to be mean of accuracy for these two outputs, I followed the available instructions:

```
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="relu"))(model)
model1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="relu"))(model)
crf1 = CRF(num_tags+1)  # CRF layer
crf2 = CRF(num_tags+1)
out1 = crf1(model)  # output
out2 = crf2(model1) 

model = Model(input, [out1, out2])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred1,  y_pred2):
    loss1 = losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred1)
    loss2 = losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred2)
    return (loss1 + loss2)/2


def Custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred1,y_pred2, k=10):
    acc1 = K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)
    acc2 = K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred1, K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)
    acc = (acc1 + acc2)/2
    return acc
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=custom_loss,metrics=Custom_accuracy)
```

but this shows the error:

```
TypeError: custom_loss() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_pred2'
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you create a minimal, reproducible example. (While the github code is helpful, not all of us can access this easily.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras)

Comment: @Vlad, thanks for the link. I followed it and created a custom loss and accuracy, but the problem is how I can feed two outputs for the loss and accuracy? now for the loss I am defining `def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred1,  y_pred2):` but the error is `TypeError: custom_loss() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_pred2'`

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by passing two loss functions to `loss` argument in `model.compile` than to pass three variables in loss function as described in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) and also make classes for [custom metric and loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#specifying_a_loss_metrics_and_an_optimizer). Make the following changes -

```
...

crf1 = CRF(num_tags+1,name="out1") <-- # change 1
crf2 = CRF(num_tags+1,name="out2") <-- # change 2
out1 = crf1(model)  
out2 = crf2(model1) 

model = Model(input, [out1, out2])

<define accuracy class and create its object> <-- # change 3
<define loss class and create its object> <-- # change 4

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", 
            loss={"out1":<loss_object_1>,"out2":<loss_object_2>},
            metrics={"out1":<accuracy_object_1>,"out2":<accuracy_object_2>}) <-- # change 5
```

Comment: thanks. in `out1 = crf1(model,name="out1") ` it gives this error: `TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: My bad! I passed ```name``` to class call function instead of class definition(or initialization). I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, @rami following your approach that problem is solved, but I have to change my custom function from `def Custom_loss(self, y_true, y_pred1, y_pred2):'  to  ` def Custom_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):' meaning just considering one output, now I wonder how the averaging is done over these two losses? I think right now the final loss is equal to loss=loss1+loss2 but I'm looking for loss=(loss1+loss2)/2

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because the output of the model is not two outputs values( like `o1,o2`), but a list of two values(like `[o1,o2]`). Try this custom loss function, hopefully it gets the issue gone:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_predsList):
    y_pred1,  y_pred2 = y_predsList
    loss1 = losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred1)
    loss2 = losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred2)
    return (loss1 + loss2)/2
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that but in custom_loss `y_pred1,  y_pred2 = y_predsList` it gives this error `TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.` then I tried `import tensorflow as tf , tf.enable_eager_execution()` but this gives error `RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.`