# When writing a custom loss function, should I use tf.reduce_mean, and if so how? Does it ever matter?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The sample code below shows that all the following give the same (correct) results when
writing a custom loss function (calculating mean_squared_error) for
a simple linear regression model.

1. Do not use tf_reduce_mean() (so returning a loss for each example)
2. Use tf_reduce_mean() (so returning a single loss)
3. Use tf_reduce_mean(..., axis-1)

Is there any reason to prefer one approach to another, and are there any circumstances
where it makes a difference?

(There is, for example sample code at
[Make a custom loss function in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras/)
that suggests axis=-1 should be used)

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Create simple dataset to do linear regression on
# The mean squared error (~ best achievable MSE loss after fitting linear regression) for this dataset is 0.01
xtrain = np.random.randn(5000)                  # Already normalized
ytrain = xtrain + np.random.randn(5000) * 0.1   # Close enough to being normalized

# Function to create model and fit linear regression, and report final loss
def cre_and_fit(loss="mean_squared_error", lossdescription="",epochs=20):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))]) 
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer="RMSProp")
    history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=epochs, verbose=False)
    print(f"Final loss value for {lossdescription}: {history.history['loss'][-1]:.4f}")

# Result from standard MSE loss ~ 0.01
cre_and_fit("mean_squared_error","Keras standard MSE")

# This gives the right result, not reducing. Return shape = (batch_size,)
cre_and_fit(lambda y_true, y_pred: (y_true-y_pred)*(y_true-y_pred),
               "custom loss, not reducing over batch items" )

# This also gives the right result, reducing over batch items. Return shape = ()
cre_and_fit(lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.reduce_mean((y_true-y_pred)*(y_true-y_pred) ),
               "custom loss, reducing over batch items")

# How about using axis=-1? Also gives the same result
cre_and_fit(lambda y_true, y_pred: tf.reduce_mean((y_true-y_pred)*(y_true-y_pred), axis=-1),
               "custom loss, reducing with axis=-1" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a lambda (or a callable in general) to `compile` and call `fit`, TF will wrap it inside a [`LossFunctionWrapper`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/losses.py#L200), which is a subclass of `Loss`, with a default *reduction type* of `ReductionV2.AUTO`. Note that a `Loss` object always has a reduction type representing how it will reduce the loss tensor to a single scalar.

Under most circumstances, `ReductionV2.AUTO` translates to `ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` which, despite its name, actually performs reduced **mean** over *all* axis on the underlying lambda's output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import losses as losses_mod
from keras.utils import losses_utils

a = tf.random.uniform((10,2))
b = tf.random.uniform((10,2))

l_auto = losses_mod.LossFunctionWrapper(fn=lambda y_true, y_pred : tf.square(y_true - y_pred), reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO)
l_sum = losses_mod.LossFunctionWrapper(fn=lambda y_true, y_pred : tf.square(y_true - y_pred), reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE)

l_auto(a,b).shape.rank == l_sum(a,b).shape.rank == 0  # rank 0 means scalar 
l_auto(a,b) == tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a - b))  # True
l_sum(a,b) == tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a - b))   # True
```

So to answer your question, the three options are equivalent since they all eventually result in a single scalar that is the mean of *all* elements in the raw `tf.square(a - b)` loss tensor. However, should you wish to perform an operation other than `reduce_mean` e.g., `reduce_sum`, *in the lambda*, then the three will yield different results:

```
l1 = losses_mod.LossFunctionWrapper(fn=lambda y_true, y_pred : tf.square(y_true - y_pred), 
                                    reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO)
l2 = losses_mod.LossFunctionWrapper(fn=lambda y_true, y_pred : tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true - y_pred)), 
                                    reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO)
l3 = losses_mod.LossFunctionWrapper(fn=lambda y_true, y_pred : tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1), 
                                    reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO)
l1(a,b) == tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a-b))  # True
l2(a,b) == tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b))   # True
l3(a,b) == tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b), axis=-1))   # True
```

Concretely, `l2(a,b) == tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b)))`, but that is just `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a-b))` since mean of a scalar is itself.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I'll take from this, I think, that it's probably advisable to reduce to a scalar in the loss function, since that's the most explicit way of coding it, the way that least relies on behind-the-scenes tf default action. Explicit is better than implicit!

Comment: That's not always the case. When you have sample weights to pass to the wrapper (along side y_true and y_pred), the Loss base class will apply the sample weights to the lambda's output before applying reduction, so if your lambda already reduces the loss to a scalar, the sample weights will lose their meaning. The best practice imo is to reduce the loss inside the lambda until the loss shape matches with the sample weights shape.