Random Forest - optimize for AUC or F1 score
I am using random forest in sklearn, and my dataset is fairly unbalanced (20% positive class, 80% other class). Is there a way to make it train (optimize) for some metric that takes this into consideration, like AUC score or F1-score? Are there any tricks that I can use to nudge it in this direction?
So far, only approach I have thought of / tried is using different class weights.
Alternatively, is there another implementation (or another model, e.g. xgboost) that would allow me such custom metric?

You could use the Balanced Random Forest from imbalanced learn.

you can use a stratified sampling approach during cross-validation or train/test splitting. This ensures that each fold or split contains a balanced representation of each class.
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)


Thank you. And what's the idea here, would I use CV for tuning some metaparameter, can you show the complete code/idea?
How about if I am not doing any CV, but want to enforce the same logic at the level of each tree in the forest, is this possible?

I assume you're dealing using random forest for binary classification. If not, you may ignore this:
To tackle a similar situation, I once used ROC to find the threshold where Youden's J statistic (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2515362/) maximises.

Yes, this is binary. But I am not referring to threshold, I just mean in the fitting process, while the loss function is being minimized. How can I customize this loss function?

Ah, I see. You can create your own loss function and use this to train your models. Hope these help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras; https://keras.io/api/losses/#:~:text=.trainable_weights))-,Creating%20custom%20losses,-Any%20callable%20with

Have you thought about oversampling the positive class? Then you can use any of the "common" models.
Here you have a lot of examples to see and investigate: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn
Regarding the metric, any should do as long as you know how analyse them properly. For example, if you are using accuracy your baseline should be 80%, since is what you would get if you predict always negative (instead of 50% that is the minimum accuracy when you have balanced classes). Personally, for this cases I like to use a mix of precision/recall and the confusion matrix.
Good luck

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
